# Is cold weather bad for tefillin?

Tags: tefilin, weather

The winter season is around the corner and I am wondering if it's damaging to leave tefillin out in the cold (I usually leave mine in a room with no heat).

Would this ruin the tefillin because of possible shrinkage?

Comment: "out in the cold" isn't exactly the same as "a room with no heat".

Comment: Scimonster, think of a storage room in the backyard.

Answer (score 6):

From [Hasofer.com](http://www.hasofer.com/page.pl?p=travel-safely-with-tefillin)

> Extremes in temperature, both heat and cold, commonly cause several
>   different types of damage to tefillin:
>
> The batim can crack. The paint of the batim and the retzuot, straps,
>   can shatter. Even the ink of the writing can crack or split away from
>   the parchment inside the batim when you're not wearing them, store
>   your tefillin at room temperature and away from direct sunlight.

Comment: My soffer friend told me the same from his experience. Don't leave them in your vehicle! Winter or summer!

Comment: What should you then do about the walk to the shul in freezing temperatures?

Comment: I can think of differences between a long deep freeze and a short walk to Shul.

Comment: @Ani put them on at home. Shulchan Aruch siman 25 siff 2. But seriously like Gershon said, we are discussing leaving it somewhere for hours our days on end. Not a short walk to shul.

Answer (score 3):

I once left my *tefillin* in my car in the middle of the Summer.  I frantically took them to a sofer in Baltimore to get checked.  He was very amused at my being worried.  He told me that it is much worse to leave them in the cold than in the heat, but that neither are much to worry about with the quality of today's *tefillin*.

(I had him check them anyways, and it turned out they were *pasul* for several unrelated reasons, and I had to get new *tefillin*.)